# Matching value only up to 8 digits in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

```
   A         B      -----sheet 2-->>    D           
Alpha RF    PT01                    Alpha RFormula  
Alpha RF    PT09                    Beta RFormula
Alpha RS    PT02                    Alpha RFormat  
Alpha RG    PT03                    Alpha RGSaf
Alpha RG    PT04                    Alpha RGFar
```

Data in Sheet 1 are taken from a machines that only support 8 digits character in naming. I want to return in Sheet 2 column E, the code in sheet 1 column B.
I am trying to use

```
=ifna(vlookup('sheet2' !LEFT(D2,8)&"*",'sheet1'!$A$2:$B$265,1,FALSE),"Not Found)
```

It would return duplicated value for many row, such as **Alpha RFormula** and **Alpha RFormat** returning PT01. The correct value should be as below:

```
Alpha RFormula  = PT01
Beta RFormula = PT99
Alpha RFormat  = PT09
Alpha RGSaf = PT04
Alpha RGFar = PT03
```

How do to it?

Comment: "Alpha RFormula" can't be differentiated from "AlphaRFormat" by the first 8 characters. if you have no additional information there can't be a solution even if you sort the items by human hands.

Comment: `sheet1'!$A$2:$B$265,1,FALSE` You are looking in Col A of Sheet1 but returning the value in first column which is A that will duplicate value .. Change it to col 2 as `'sheet1'!$A$2:$B$265,2,FALSE` ... Thoug it will not work as suggested by @Variatus

Comment: @Variatus Yep ,that's also what blocked me here. This is an attendance machines so it records everyone IDs on it.  But the machines only limited to have 8 digit char recorded..

Comment: If you can't change the machine, change the ID's. You need IDs that are unique within their first 8 digits. That would allow you to have 10 million employees. Fire the guy who invented the useless IDs and your company is on its way to greater efficiency. (I hope it wasn't the boss.)

Comment: The ID is not the problem, rather the Name is the problem. It only allow to input Name up to 8 digits. Well, actually we did have thousand of people here..and this problem found just today after 10 years of operation of this plant..lol

Answer (score 0):

Just change the range to look in. This may helps you:

**Formula:**

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT($D1,8),$A$1:$B$5,2,FALSE),"Not Found")`

[image]